# vhdl choose first vector and reset all other

Tags: vhdl, hardware

I'm doing a project in VHDL, and I need some help.

I have some `std_logic_vector`s in an array type, for example let's say:

```
vector(0) = "00"
vector(1) = "00"
vector(2) = "00"
vector(3) = "01"
vector(4) = "00"
vector(5) = "01"
vector(6) = "11"
vector(7) = "11"
vector(8) = "11"
```

then what I want my combinational logic to do is find the first vector that is equal to `"01"` and make all vectors after that equal to `"11"`
For our example would be:

```
vector(0)= "00"
vector(1)= "00"
vector(2)= "00"
vector(3)= "01"
vector(4)= "11"
vector(5)= "11"
vector(6)= "11"
vector(7)= "11"
vector(8)= "11"
```

any idea how to do it?

Comment: A good way would be to use a _for loop_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a loop.  Assume you have the following array definition:

```
type vector_array is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal vector : vector_array(0 to 8);
signal vector_out : vector_array(0 to 8);
```

You can then find the first "01" with the following example (and there are many ways to do it).  This example takes `vector` and creates `vector_out`.

```
process(vector)
  variable found : boolean;
begin
  found := false;
  for i in vector'range loop
    if ( found ) then
      vector_out(i) <= "11";
    else
      vector_out(i) <= vector(i);
      if ( vector(i) = "01" ) then
        found := true;
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
end process;
```

Comment: just a question, is this variable synthesizable?

Comment: Yes it is.  Variables in general are synthesizable (there are exceptions, such as some shared variables).